# Vuetify Data tables и Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Пытаюсь вывести данные в таблицу с помощью axios. В основе таблица #8 Paginate and sort server-side отсюда https://vuetifyjs.com/components/data-tables. Изменил только метод getUsers, выглядит это так

```
getUsers () {
    var self = this;
    return axios.get('http://localhost/api/items')
      .then(function(res) {

          self.items = res.data;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {

          return Promise.reject(err.status);
    });
  }
```

Работает, но не совсем - в консоли получаю

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: items.sort is not a function

Собственно вопрос, как правильно сделать ajax запрос то ?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужен массив а возвращается объект ?

Comment: При получении данных сделайте console.dir(res.data) и посмотрите, что вам там приходит